# IIS Server Name Change

Tags: iis, iis-5

I have a certificate for that is valid for *.MyCompany.**com**.  That is fine for my dev and test servers because the first part of the URLs for those computers ends like that.

I want to test this on my computer and the certificate is incorrect because my computer defaults to the url MyComputer.MyCompany.**net**.

Is there a way to fake out IIS in to thinking that my computer is .MyCompany.**com** or am I out of luck when it comes to testing this?

Thanks,
Vaccano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to edit the host header values for the IIS website to accept *.Mycompany.com. To get the DNS to resolve and work correctly, you may need to add an entry to your windows hosts file -- mycomputer.mycompany.com 127.0.0.1. that will let you test locally.

Another option would be to use a self-signed cert for local development.

Comment: Changing the header was the part I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you could edit your hosts file and add an entry to point http://you.yourcompany.com to your local ip or 127.0.0.1

Edit c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts with a text editor.

save it and you should be able to hit your own IIS using the new fake name.